# Error: unused arguments in Shiny (R)

Tags: r, shiny

I wanted to begin by modifying a few components of one of the basic shiny example apps, but I keep getting this error:

```
ERROR: unused arguments (fluidRow(column(4, tags$hr(),
 verbatimTextOutput("out1"), selectInput("in1", "Options", choices =
 state.name, multiple = TRUE, selectize = FALSE))), fluidRow(column(4,
 tags$hr(), verbatimTextOutput("out2"), selectInput("in2", "Options",
 choices = state.name, multiple = TRUE, selectize = FALSE))))
```

Here is my code:

## ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

shinyUI(fluidPage(theme=shinytheme("flatly"),
  #Application Title
  headerPanel("States"),
  br(),
  fluidRow(
    column(4, 
           tags$h4("Choose One or Multiple States"))
  )),
  fluidRow(
    column(4,
           tags$hr(),
           verbatimTextOutput('out1'),
           selectInput('in1', 'Options', choices = state.name, multiple = TRUE, selectize = FALSE)
           )
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(4,
           tags$hr(),
           verbatimTextOutput('out2'),
           selectInput('in2', 'Options', choices= state.name, multiple = TRUE, selectize = FALSE))
  ))
```

===============================================

## server.R

```
sessionInfo()
install.packages("shiny")
library(shiny)

View(headcount)
attach(headcount)
headcount.crn=as.array(CRN)


shinyServer(function (input, output, session) {
  output$out1 <- renderPrint(input$in1)
  output$out2 <- renderPrint(input$in2)
  })
```

Comment: Sometimes you get this kind of errors because `R` is not updated to latest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That error usually means that you messed up your commas or brackets somewhere. In your case, there's one too many closing brackets (`)`) at the end of the first `fluidRow` that's closing the `fluidPage` prematurely

Comment: Didn't catch that at all-- it works fine now! Thank you!

Comment: Indeed, "messed up your commas or brackets somewhere" sums it up nicely!

Answer (score 1):

In my case this was coming from the ambiguity when I loaded two packages using library(packageName) both having the same function name. So anyone who ended up here debugging can also consider that possibility in case whats written above is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

if anyone encounters selectInput:unused argument c("Cylinders"="cyl") kind of error use 'list' instead of 'c' there

i had same problem i used and it worked